# How to set image path in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to display already stored database image in template. But here i'm getting only name of the image. How to solve this, Where i did mistake.

models.py

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
def display(request):
     myimages_objs = Images.objects.all().values()
     for i in myimages_objs :
          myimages_objs = i['image']
          return render(request, 'index.html', {'myimages_obj ': myimages_objs })
```

index.html

```
<div class="divi">
   <img src="{{ myimages_obj }}" alt="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are returning the objects inside the for loop, this causes only a single image to be displayed in the template. Instead of doing this, you can pass all the image objects in the template, then loop through the objects in the template to display the images.

You can change your view as:

```
def display(request):
    myimages_objs = Images.objects.all() # get all the images
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'myimages_objs':myimages_objs})
```

Then in your template:

```
<div class="divi">
    {% for item in myimages_objs %} //loop through all the images
        <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="image">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**Edit:**

**Change the *upload_to* to *upload_to="images/"*.**

As far as I am concerned, your images are not being stored inside the `images` folder as you have missed the backslash(which represents a folder name). So, the images are being saved inside the `media` folder.

But the image url is something like `project_path/media/images/something.jpg` which cannot be found as the images are not being saved inside the `images` folder.

**Change the field as stated for new images to be stored in the specified folder. For old images, copy them to the images folder manually.**

I hope this will help.

Comment: i tried this but its not displaying anything. How to set image path.

Comment: can you check if the images are being stored in the media/images/ folder?

Comment: images are stored in media folder. i dont have any folder inside media

Comment: Are all your images named as `images` in the media folder?

Comment: After this, upload new images, and see if the recently added images are being displayed.

Comment: I have updated my answer for more clarification. Do have a look at it.

Comment: thing is images not saved inside images folder its saved inside media folder only i think this is why its not displaying

Comment: That's right. So try adding the backslash in the upload_to field and check it.